# Meteor - Syntax Highlighting from Reactive Session Key with Prism.js

Tags: meteor

I'm displaying a selected user's raw JSON on an admin panel. The selected user gets changed reactively from a Session key. I want the JSON syntax highlighted by Prism.js each time the user changes, but currently Prism only runs once when my template is rendered and does not re-run after the node is removed and replaced by Blaze. What's the best way to get the syntax highlighted anew each time the Session key changes?

By way of detail:

I grab a user from a template helper:

```
Template.admin_user_detail.helpers({
  selectedUser: function(){
    var item = Session.get("adminItem");
    return item && Users.findOne(item);
  }
});
```

I display its JSON in the template as follows:

```
UI.registerHelper("adminItemAsJSON", function(object){
  return JSON.stringify(object, undefined, 4);
});
```

Prism then runs correctly the first time to highlight it as follows:

```
Template.admin_user_detail.rendered = function(){
  var
    self = this,
    code = self.find('code');
  Prism.highlightElement(code);
}
```

It makes sense to me that when I run `Session.set("adminItem")` Prism does not run again, because Blaze is not removing and re-rendering the template. So where do I need to place the `Prism.highlightElement()` piece?  Is it a `Deps.autorun()` or another pattern and can someone point the way with a bit of sample code?

Everything else works fine including the reactivity piece. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered yourself : `Deps.autorun` solves your problem:

```
Template.List.rendered = function(){
   var self = this;
   this.deps = Deps.autorun(function(){

       // whenever adminItem is changed then this function reruns.
       Session.get("adminItem");

       code = self.find('code');
       Prism.highlightElement(code);
   })
};
Template.List.destroyed = function(){
   // remember to stop
   this.deps.stop();
};
```

Comment: This did the trick. I did not think of placing the autorun inside the rendered function, which in retrospect makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `Prism.highlightAll();`.